# Low level access to files (txt,csv) under R (reading in only chosen lines, without reading whole file into memory)

Tags: r, perl, csv, bigdata

Is there any simple R function to read specific lines from text files (*.txt or especially *.csv) without reading the whole file into memory? I would like to read in only chosen lines of the file, for example reading only lines with `x1==b`:

```
x1 x2 x3
a  1  1
a  2  2
b  2  3
b  1  4
a  2  1
->   
x1 x2 x3
b  2  3
b  1  4
```

maybe some Perl tool for R, but is it easy (for R user)?

Comment: you can use `readLines` to read chunks at a time ... or `read.table` with the `skip` and `nrows` arguments set ...  however, if you've got access to external filters (as Dirk suggests below), you can just say `grep "^b" myfile.txt >body.txt; head -1 myfile.txt >header.txt; cat header.txt body.txt >small.txt`

Comment: You can find some interesting solution here illposed.net - lazy.frame

Comment: I would use @Ben's solution but also see this: http://colbycol.r-forge.r-project.org/

Answer (score 2):

The default `read.*` functions all read everything by default.  So one option is to use an external filter --- as e.g. an awk or sed script, or a grep expression --- and then to read via `read.table()` from that stream after having filtered.